# Powershell2 call from matlab is blocked

Tags: matlab, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

The wierdest thing!

Powershell.exe Get-Help is working from cmd as expected and i get back the cmd prompt.

Now, calling the exact command from Matlab system command
system('Powershell.exe Get-Help');

is blocked and waiting for hitting the return key.

The even more strange thing is that it happens only on computer with ps2 but on other pc with ps3 it is working just fine.

Any reason / workarounds are welcome

Comment: Isn't this an OS-side issue? Like windows not allowing a program to run an exe, but it fails to ask for your permission? Matlab shouldn't care about what you run with it.

Comment: Thanks andras. This is sure not failing. It just blocked and wait for me to hit the return key. After hitting the return, i get the proper result.

Comment: want to inform that we've managed to found an ugly workaround to simulate the enter with
Powershell.exe Get-Help < enter.txt


when enter.txt includes the \r character.
Credit goes to Harry MacDowel. [link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/309681)

Comment: Thanks for the update, ugly indeed!:) But the problem itself is ugly. If workaround, you could also try to make MATLAB itself simulate an enter, I *think* this could be done with `robot = java.awt.Robot(); robot.keyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);`.

Comment: Will not work as matlab is blocked -> i dont have the chance to call the robot

Comment: Ooh, I see, sorry. Yeah, then you really have to hack it from inside the system call, as you wrote:)